# Create URL for detailview using DRF Modelviewset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

i'm using DRF modelviewset to create an api for users model. Can anyone explain or help how can I pass a url in react-native for the `detailview` of user. Right now i'm getting the detailview in this manner `127.0.0.1:8000/users/users/2/`. But everytime i don't want to pass the id in the url.

`models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """This Class is used to extend the in-build user model """
    ROLE_CHOICES = (('CREATOR','CREATOR'),('MODERATOR','MODERATOR'),('USERS','USERS'))
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('MALE','MALE'),('FEMALE',"FEMALE"),('OTHER','OTHER'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth', null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_images', verbose_name='Profile Image', default='media/profile_images/default.webp', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(verbose_name='Bio')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Role', choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='USERS')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='Gender', choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    following = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    followers = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','password','email','date_of_birth',
                  'profile_image','bio','role','gender', 'following','followers')
        extra_kwargs = {'is_active':{'write_only':True},
                        'password':{'write_only':True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        logger.info('Information Stored!')
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().update( *args, **kwargs)
        p = user.password
        user.set_password(p)
        user.save()
        return user
```

`views.py`

```
class UserAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    # permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]

    def get_queryset(self):
        users = User.objects.all()
        return users
```

`urls.py`

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', views.UserAPI, basename='users'),
router.register('following', views.FollowingAPI, basename='following'),


urlpatterns = router.urls
```

How can i solve this. Need your help please. Thank you

Comment: You want to get details of current authenticated user right?

Comment: Yes @Sumithran. The user who has registered & want to view his entire profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`@action`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) decorator.

Give this a try:

```
class UserAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   ...

    @action(detail=False)
    def profile(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now go to [127.0.0.1:8000/users/profile/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/profile/), you should see the current authenticated user's data.

Comment: No man it's not working. `AttributeError at /users/profile/`.

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback?

Comment: Can you share the full error traceback?

Comment: Make sure you have logged in?

Comment: Can you please tell how can I logged in through browseable api? please

Comment: The error i'm getting is `AttributeError at /users/users/profile/'
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `bio` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `AnonymousUser` instance.
Original exception text was: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'bio'.

Comment: Your user is not authenticated, to authenticate go to localhost:800/admin

Comment: I have logged in admin. But still the same error

Comment: Are you still getting ```AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'bio```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241063/discussion-between-aakash-bhaikatti-and-sumithran).

Comment: Can you tell how can a user be updated then?

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful.
You can use `user = request.user.id` , by in this way you can get current login user.

Comment: can u explain with the code. As i'm new in these

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).